# axios in react works locally but doesn't work in heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, axios

I used axios twice. onces on internal api in my express server, and once external api in react. Getting internal api from express to react works, but getting external api in react is not working

It does work locally but it's doing nothing when deployed in heroku

Below code is where getting api data doesn't work. Also I can't find any record of getting the data when I check the log in heroku

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

export default function Weather() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState("");
  const [currentWeather, setCurrentWeather] = useState("");
  const [feelsLike, setFeelsLiks] = useState("");
  const [tempMax, setTempMax] = useState("");
  const [tempMin, setTempMin] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(
      "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Seoul&appid=4a80048ac273c6f7e70908e2bb631fee"
    ).then((response) => {
      setWeather(response.data.weather[0].main);
      setCurrentWeather(Math.floor(response.data.main.temp - 273));
      setFeelsLiks(Math.floor(response.data.main.feels_like - 273));
      setTempMax(Math.floor(response.data.main.temp_max - 273));
      setTempMin(Math.floor(response.data.main.temp_min - 273));
    });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Weather</h3>
      <div id="displayWeather">
        <p>{weather}</p>
        <p>temp: {currentWeather}°</p>
        <p>feels like: {feelsLike}°</p>
        <p>Max temp: {tempMax}°</p>
        <p>Min temp: {tempMin}°</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and below is where getting data works

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

export default function News() {
  const [recentNews, setRecentNews] = useState([]);
  const [newsUrl, setNewsUrl] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("api/newsname").then((response) => {
      setRecentNews(response.data);
    });
    Axios.get("/api/newsurl").then((response) => {
      setNewsUrl(response.data);
    });
  });

  const data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < recentNews.length; i++) {
    data.push(<a href={newsUrl[i]}>{recentNews[i]}</a>);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>News</h3>
      <div id="displayNews">
        {data.map((element) => {
          return <li className="list">{element}</li>;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In dev tools, do you see any of the network requests?

Comment: @Dean James heroku logs shows that requests api from the server is on, but not on external api

Comment: @Apeiron That is not what Dean meant, in the browser devtools can you see the request?

Comment: Sorry for my bad understaning. After looking the dev tools, I realized that it's a problem of http, https. Thank you!